# Using same button to Play/Pause and loop audio in AVFoundation

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, avfoundation

I have tried linking the action to the same button but this stops the button from working altogether. I can get it working using the same code if I create a separate button:

```
@IBAction func Play(sender: AnyObject) {
    SoundPlayer.play()
}

@IBAction func stop(sender: AnyObject) {        
    SoundPlayer.stop()
}
```

I also need the audio to loop.

Using Nirav code:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

   var SoundPlayer:AVAudioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer()

   @IBOutlet var btnPlay: UIButton!
   @IBOutlet var btnStop: UIButton!

   override func viewDidLoad() {
      super.viewDidLoad()

      let FileLocation = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("Aspirin", ofType: ".mp3")


      do {
          SoundPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: NSURL(fileURLWithPath: FileLocation!))


          try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryAmbient)
          try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true)

      }

      catch {
          print(error)
      }

   }

   override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
      super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
   }

   @IBAction func btnTap(sender: UIButton) {
      if (sender == self.btnPlay) {
      }
      else if (sender == self.btnStop) {
      }
   }
}
```

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tdgan.png) - Screenshot of storyboard

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that just create `IBOutlet` of both button like this

```
@IBOutlet var btnPlay: UIButton!
```

Now bind this action to both button

```
@IBaction func btnTap(sender: UIButton) {
     if (!sender.selected) {
         SoundPlayer.play()
     }
     else {
         SoundPlayer.stop()
     }
     sender.selected = !sender.selected
}
```

Hope this will help you

Comment: Getting NS invalid argument exception (see revised code in original post)

Comment: where you getting that?

Comment: When pressing the button in the simulator

Comment: Have you set both button same `Action` and remove the previous one.

Comment: Yes - I recreated it in a fresh project and linked the button to both outlets and the action.

Comment: Can you show me the screen shot of story board. Because for me it is working perfectly.

Comment: Screenshot added to original post

Comment: Replace your whole `btnTap` with my one. I have edited answer.

Comment: It now plays the audio but it does not pause it when the button is pressed again

Comment: I have edited answer .Please check that. Also remove `btnStop` from viewController  as well as strory board button reference two.

Comment: Approved. Did you know how to make the audio loop as it is currently ending?

Comment: I dont't understand what you try to say. Put a new question with more detail i will check that.